# Crop multiple pdf in a folder using ghostscript

Tags: excel, vba, ghostscript

I have write a macro that crop single pdf in ghostscript. It work

```
Sub Ghostcrop()
Dim fname As String

    fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:= _
    "PDF Files(*.pdf),*.pdf", Title:="Seleziona PDF")


    RetVal = Shell("gswin32c.exe -o " & fname & "_MONTAGGIO" & ".pdf" & " -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1200 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=850 -dFIXEDMEDIA -f " & fname, 0)

End Sub
```

but when i try to run this script on ALL file in a choose folder, it run smootly but don't do nothing.

```
Sub LoopCrop()
    Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
    Dim xDFileDlg As FileDialog

Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = "Scegliere la cartella di destinazione:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

    file = Dir(xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.item(1) & "\*.pdf")
    While (file <> "")
        RetVal = Shell("gswin32c.exe -o " & file & "_MONTAGGIO" & ".pdf" & " -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1200 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=850 -dFIXEDMEDIA -f " & file, 0)
        file = Dir()
    Wend
End Sub
```

NO errors, no stopping. Someone can help?

edit: the error is a space in path. How i can convert long path in short path?

Comment: This seems likely to be fixable by adding extra `"` arround your file name. Basically changing  `-o " & file & "_MONTAGGIO" & ".pdf"` to `-o """ & file & "_MONTAGGIO" & ".pdf"""`.

Comment: My pleasure. :-)